# how to make a field editable only if another is not blank in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

I want to be able to edit a field in Rails_Admin only if another is not blank

To be more specific, i want to be able to edit the "description" for an image only if there is an image already uploaded for this specific instance of the object

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :uploaded_image
    field :image_description
  end
end
```

So in my admin, i don't want to display the field :image_description unless the uploaded_image field is not blank.

Any clues ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that this will only work once the record has been saved, but the following configuration will let `image_description` be visible only if `uploaded_image` is present.

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :uploaded_image
    field :image_description do
      visible do
        bindings[:object].uploaded_image.present?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your information is it possible to do this "live". For example when I make something present another thing should appear.

Comment: With my solution, no. You'll need Javascript to do that.